# Sublime Regex extract

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

```
<.*>|\n.*\s.*\sid="(\w*)".*\n+|.*>\n|\n.+

and replace $1
```

This regex can take all id out from file

```
<a href="java" class="total" id="maker" placeholder="getTheResult('local6')">master6<a>
```

> Result is maker

How can I extract getTheResult key name?

> so my result will be local6

```
Tried   <.*>|\n.*\s.*\sgetTheResult('(\w*)').*\n+|.*>\n|\n.+ but didn't helped
```

Comment: No idea why you need that strange regex, but if you want to match a `(` or `)`, you need to escape them. `getTheResult\('(\w*\)')`

Comment: Don't parse HTML with regex. Use the DOM

Comment: @trincot What's wrong with using regex for this extraction?

Comment: getTheResult\('(\w*\)') this will not work

Comment: I meant  `getTheResult\('(\w*)'\)` (the literal parentheses are those outside `''`). Could you provide a bit more of the input file? I doubt you need that much of a pattern here.

Comment: I'd use this `getTheResult\('([^']*)'\)|(?:(?!getTheResult\(')[\s\S])*` and replace with `$1\n`. Please check.

Comment: yes it did worked do you know how can i added space or , between extracted words , Thanks If i use $1, it adds , multiple times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that:

- you have files with text like `getTheResult('local6')`
- you may have several values like that on a line
- you'd like to keep those text only, one value per line.

I suggest

```
getTheResult\('([^']*)'\)|(?:(?!getTheResult\(')[\s\S])*
```

and replace with `$1\n`. The `\n` will insert a newline between the values. You can then use `^\n` regex (to replace with empty string) to remove empty lines.

**Pattern details**:

- `getTheResult\('` -  matches `getTheResult('` as a literal string (note the `(` is escaped)
- `([^']*)`  - Group 1 capturing 0+ chars other than `'`
- `'\)` - a literal `')`
- `|` - or
- `(?:(?!getTheResult\(')[\s\S])*` - 0+ chars that are not starting chars of the `getTheResult('` character sequence (this is a [**tempered greedy token**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970)).